# Weird behavior in linking table creation in EF Core, adding it in the DbContext but shows two versions in the migration file

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a weird behavior happening in my code.

I've created a `Place` entity and a `SubCategory` entity.
Because it is a many to many relationship, I created a `PlaceSubCategory` entity with a composite key.

Now, here's what its creation looks like in the `DbContext`:

```cs
public DbSet<PlaceSubCategory> PlaceSubCategories { get; set; }
```

And here's what it creates in the migration file:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "PlaceSubCategories",
    columns: table => new
    {
        PlaceId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        SubCategoryId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        CreatedDateTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "getutcdate()")
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_PlaceSubCategories", x => new { x.PlaceId, x.SubCategoryId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PlaceSubCategories_Places_PlaceId",
            column: x => x.PlaceId,
            principalTable: "Places",
            principalColumn: "PlaceId");
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PlaceSubCategories_SubCategories_SubCategoryId",
            column: x => x.SubCategoryId,
            principalTable: "SubCategories",
            principalColumn: "SubCategoryId");
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "PlaceSubCategory",
    columns: table => new
    {
        PlacesPlaceId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        SubCategoriesSubCategoryId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_PlaceSubCategory", x => new { x.PlacesPlaceId, x.SubCategoriesSubCategoryId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PlaceSubCategory_Places_PlacesPlaceId",
            column: x => x.PlacesPlaceId,
            principalTable: "Places",
            principalColumn: "PlaceId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_PlaceSubCategory_SubCategories_SubCategoriesSubCategoryId",
            column: x => x.SubCategoriesSubCategoryId,
            principalTable: "SubCategories",
            principalColumn: "SubCategoryId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

It creates the table twice, which I thought was the default behaviour in EF Core to create a background linking table and so it shows in the migration file, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Also, here's the configuration file for `PlaceSubCategory` (and not PlaceSubCategories):

```cs
public class PlaceSubCategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PlaceSubCategory>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PlaceSubCategory> builder)
    {
        // define the composite key for PlaceSubCategory table
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.PlaceId, x.SubCategoryId });

        builder.HasOne<Place>(d => d.Place)
            .WithMany(d => d.SubCategoriesLink)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PlaceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne<SubCategory>(d => d.SubCategory)
            .WithMany(d => d.PlacesLink)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SubCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.CreatedDateTime)
            .HasConversion(AppDbContext.utcConverter)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");
    }
}
```

But it isn't taking it into account, as you can see by the delete behavior being non-existent in the `PlaceSubCategories` creation, but there's an automatically set delete behavior for
`PlaceSubCategory` that's not what I set in the configuration file.

And of course the configuration has been set:

```
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PlaceSubCategoryConfiguration());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that by creating this linking entity I was doing what EF Core would do anyway which is to create a linking entity in the background that would be showing in the migration file. So my entity got created and EF Core's as well without warning.
I deleted my entity and the EF Core's automatically created linking entity got added to the migration file, which seems fine and the same thing as if I created it.